Certbot redirection to HTTPS works only for one host
After installing SSL certificates using Certbot and nginx (Ubuntu 22.10) my config file is this:
server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    root /var/www/html/example/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }   

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

If I understand correctly, the second server section should redirect any request for example.com or www.example.com to https.
When in my browser I type http://example.com it redirects correctly to https://example.com. But when I type: http://www.example.com it opens the non-secure page instead of redirecting.
Why the second way does not work?
